# Why do we not have software SIM cards?

Tags: mobile-phone, sim

As apple and other phone manufacturers continue to require smaller and smaller sim cards (now the nano sim with the iPad Air) surely the question must arise as to why we can't simply have a software sim card that negates the necessity to have a physical sim at all.

Presumably it would be a simply enough to create a system that could authenticate to a network without any physical sim card.

- Are there any technical reasons why this won't happen?
- Is there currently any companies working on this?

Comment: This is off-topic for SU - it's not about computers. It also doesn't really work with SE's Q/A format - too much speculation. We would be happy to discuss it in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118/root-access) if you wanted, though.

Comment: Surely Phones are computers now, and a question about why I need a dongle to use it should be on topic!

Comment: Offtopic and I've VTC'ed.  Anyway, this was sort of tried with CDMA - many 3G CDMA phones in the US don't use SIM cards.  Maybe network providers got tired of people calling into their customer service centers to move phones around all the time.

Comment: What does VTC'ed mean?

Comment: Voted To Close.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wyf-9CPyBsY&feature=youtu.be

Comment: @AnuragUniyal a youtube url posted without any comment is likely to be flagged as spam.  Perhaps you should post it as an answer rather than a comment

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason is security.

SIM card is not just an ordinary piece of read-only memory. It's a separate micro-computer with its own environment capable of running [Java Card](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Card) applets. They can communicate with network provider and he can modify them over the air to some extent. For example when you want to change network provider, but keep your old phone number, you are provided with a "blank" SIM card from the new provider which is later programmed with your phone number and the old SIM card is cancelled.

SIM cards can have multiple applets installed. For example you can have your SIM card integrated with [PayPass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MasterCard#PayPass). With such SIM card, you can use your [NFC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near_field_communication)-enabled smartphone as a wireless debit card.

Modern SIM cards cannot be cloned (except for some that use [outdated encryption standards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sim_card#Security)). But copying software is easy. Actually, your concept of software-based SIM cards implies the ability to copy them - if you could move the SIM from one phone to another, then you could copy it too. Preventing it on software level is not an option, because phone software can be modified by regular user (for example Android is open-source software and you can modify it yourself, then flash it to your phone). So with software SIMs, you can have two phones with identical SIM and that's no good. What's worse, you could clone that PayPass applet. Anybody could clone it. It's like a magnetic-strip credit card that can be cloned and used to steal your money.

Answer (score 1):

Before this whole question gets marked as offtopic...

With a physical SIM card, I can swap my SIM from any network provider to any other network provider.

I can do this whenever I want, wherever I want and without having to ask for permission from the phone manufacturer, my existing network provider or a new third party - all of which may refuse my request.

If you move to the SIM being software only, you will lose one or more of these freedoms.

Comment: I think a system could be easily designed that would not prevent anyone from changing at any time.  Having a sim card in your phone is a bit like needing a dongle for you pc to connect to the internet.

Comment: That system wouldn't work 30,000 feet up in the air in an aeroplane with no mobile signal or data. A dongle gives you the technical capability to connect to the internet, a SIM gives you the right to connect to the internet provider, a subtle difference.